# Difference between admin and super admin?

Tags: standards, difference, terms-of-service

In our company we use the term admin and super admin.

Admin - refers to the person who will handle the users, this is preferably from the external (maybe a manager of our client)

Superadmin - refers to the person who will handle the admins, preferably this is internal (a personnel that should be working in our company)

But I am looking for the standard definition of those, I've tried searching it on google but [all of the results correspond to specific system](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=admin%20and%20superadmin) (like wordpress, google, etc) and they are the one who defines it.

Is there a standard definition of admin and superadmin?

Comment: Please help, try to explain why my question is being down voted?

Comment: Questions about the names of things are [controversial](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582).  Given the existence of dictionaries, these kinds of questions are just not all that interesting, especially on a site which is supposed to be devoted to answering questions about software design.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has absolutely nothing to do with conceptual software development.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a standard definition of admin and superadmin?

No, there isn't.

SuperAdmin is just a word that was made up when someone needed to create a new role with more powers than ordinary admins.  In a prior job, we created a 'Super Admin' role when we modified a particular piece of software to have multi-tenant capabilities; the super-admin was allowed access to all tenants, while the Admin role was restricted to the tenant to whom they were assigned.